# Chart Y axis switch between autoscale and manual range

Tags: c#, vb.net, charts, visual-studio-2015

I want to create a chart such that the user can choose to autoscale the y axis and also be able to manually change the axis at runtime. I am able to autoscale until the y Axis hasnt been changed using the updowns, however as soon I change any up down, the autoscale is unresponsive.

```
 private void numUD_Graph_Ymax_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int newmax = (int)numUD_Graph_Ymax.Value;
            int allowedmin = (int)numUD_Graph_Ymax.Minimum;
            int allowedmax = (int)numUD_Graph_Ymax.Maximum;

            if (newmax >= allowedmin && newmax <= allowedmax && newmax > chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum)
            {
                chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = newmax;
                chart.Update();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void numUD_Graph_Ymin_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int newmin = (int)numUD_Graph_Ymin.Value;
            int allowedmin = (int)numUD_Graph_Ymin.Minimum;
            int allowedmax = (int)numUD_Graph_Ymin.Maximum;

            if (newmin >= allowedmin && newmin <= allowedmax && newmin < chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum)
            {
                chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = newmin;
                chart.Update();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
        }
    }
```

And this is my button handler for autoscaling visible data:

```
        private void btn_AutoSize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chart.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale();
        chart.Update();
        updateUI();

    }
private void updateUI()
    {
            numUD_Graph_Xmin.Value = (decimal)chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum;
            numUD_Graph_Xmax.Value = (decimal)chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum;
            numUD_Graph_XInterval.Value = (decimal)chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval;
            numUD_Graph_Ymin.Value = (decimal)chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum;
            numUD_Graph_Ymax.Value = (decimal)chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum;

    }
```

Where am I going wrong? How do I autoscale and load the new coordiates in the numeric up downs while also allowing the user to further modify the graph using the up downs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to bringing back the automatic scaling after having set one of the `Axis`'s `Minimum` and/or `Maximum` values is to **reset** (all) those values:

```
private void btn_AutoSize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = double.NaN;  /// <-- this is the magic 'number'
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = double.NaN;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = double.NaN;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = double.NaN;


 // not quite sure about these lines
 /*  
    chart.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale();  
    chart.Update();
    updateUI();

 */

}
```

Notes:

- [`RecalculateAxesScale`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartarea.recalculateaxesscale%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) shouldn't be necessary as you didn't code the [Customize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.customize(v=vs.110).aspx) event.
- `updateUI();` it is really hard to to set those `NumericUpDowns` to helpful values since they only accept numbers and don't know a state 'unset' except being disabled.

I would drop the button for a `CheckBox cbx_AutoRange {Text = "Automatic Range"}` and actually disable the `numUD` when it changes to `Checked`. Upon unchecking it I would set the values to the current min/max values in the `Series` maybe like this:

```
private void cbx_AutoRange_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cbx_AutoRange.Checked)
    {
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = double.NaN;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = double.NaN;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = double.NaN;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = double.NaN;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = double.NaN;

        numUD_Graph_Xmin.Enabled = false;
        numUD_Graph_Xmax.Enabled = false;
        numUD_Graph_XInterval.Enabled = false;
        numUD_Graph_Ymin.Enabled = false;
        numUD_Graph_Ymax.Enabled = false;

    }
    else
    {
        numUD_Graph_Xmin.Enabled = true;
        numUD_Graph_Xmin.Value = (decimal)chart1.Series[0].Points.FindMinByValue().XValue;
        numUD_Graph_Xmax.Value = (decimal)chart1.Series[0].Points.FindMaxByValue().XValue;
      //.. etc
      //.. etc

    }

}
```

Not sure why you have code for both axes if you only want to turn autoscaling up for only one?